# App store uploading(64-bit not supporting) issue with Cocos2dxv3.0-pre-alpha0

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have developed a game with Cocos2dxv3.0-pre-alpha0 and while uploading the game on app store,i have stuck with an issue that the project is missing 64-bit support as below:-

[image]

then i have changed the architecture from 32-bit to 64-bit but then i got a lot of errors(201) related to cocos2dx referencing as below:-

[image]

I have searched for this issue,then i got the solution that libcocos2dx is not running for 64-bit then i have changed the architecture for libcocos2dx as below:-

[image]

then after running,i got issues related to libcurl:-

[image]

for this,i have searching for more than 5 days and got a link as below

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/v3-0-curl-https-request-crash-on-ios7-64-bit/13549/4

In this link,one link is mentioned for updated libcurl but that is not working now.
Can anyone suggest where i can find the updated libcurl or any other solution for uploading the game with this cocos2dx version(Cocos2dxv3.0-pre-alpha0) only.

Thanks.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for sticking with pre alpha0?

Comment: Actually the project is already developed with this version of Cocos2dx.
and i have updated the libcurl and resolved this issue.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have resolved this major issue by updating the curl library successfully.
Following link helped me to resolve this issue:-

https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios